# Creating relationship class in ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class

I can not seem to create a relationship class in ArcSDE, or at least one that works.

I am succseful in creating the class however ArcMap does not recongnize it (there are no related tables shown) and if I click on relationship classes properties in the context menu in ArcCatalog I get the following error message:

[image]

Again the relationship class is created succesfully the results are included. I get the same if I use the catalog tree, toolbox or python script.

[image]

Comment: This is an old Question.  If the problem persists would you be able to edit it and update it with the version of ArcGIS and the DBMS version that you currently use when seeing this, please?